# Ajax not sending file upload data to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been having trouble getting my ajax script to properly post to my php file. I've done various checks, and my ajax is definitely registering the image files, but it's not posting to the php (it echos no data set). Any idea why the file isn't being posted? Here is the AJAX and PHP:

```
$(function()
{
// Variable to store your files
var files;

// Add events
$('input[type=file]').on('change', prepareUpload);
$("form").submit(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation(); // Stop stuff happening
    event.preventDefault(); // Totally stop stuff happening

    // START A LOADING SPINNER HERE

    // Create a formdata object and add the files
    var data = new FormData();

    $.each(files, function(key, value)
    {
        console.log(files);
        data.append(key, value);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '../api/frs-upload.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false, // Don't process the files
        contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            if(typeof data.error === 'undefined')
            {
                // Success so call function to process the form
                submitForm(event, data);
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle errors here
                console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            // Handle errors here
            console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
            // STOP LOADING SPINNER
        }
    });
});

// Grab the files and set them to our variable
function prepareUpload(event)
{
    files = event.target.files;
    for (var i = 0, file; file = files[i]; i++) {
        console.log(file);
    }
}

// Catch the form submit and upload the files
function uploadFiles(event)
{
    event.stopPropagation(); // Stop stuff happening
    event.preventDefault(); // Totally stop stuff happening

    // START A LOADING SPINNER HERE

    // Create a formdata object and add the files
    var data = new FormData();

    $.each(files, function(key, value)
    {
        alert("test");

        alert(key + ": " + value)
        data.append(key, value);
    });


    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/frs-upload.php?files',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false, // Don't process the files
        contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            if(typeof data.error === 'undefined')
            {
                // Success so call function to process the form
                submitForm(event, data);
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle errors here
                console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            // Handle errors here
            console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
            // STOP LOADING SPINNER
        }
    });
}

function submitForm(event, data)
{
    // Create a jQuery object from the form
    $form = $(event.target);

    // Serialize the form data
    var formData = $form.serialize();

    // You should sterilise the file names
    $.each(data.files, function(key, value)
    {
        formData = formData + '&filenames[]=' + value;
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'submit.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            if(typeof data.error === 'undefined')
            {
                // Success so call function to process the form
                console.log('SUCCESS: ' + data.success);
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle errors here
                console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            // Handle errors here
            console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
        },
        complete: function()
        {
            // STOP LOADING SPINNER
        }
    });
}
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if($_FILES['file']['name']){
$data = array();

    $error = false;
    $files = array();

    $uploaddir = 'uploads/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)){
            $files[] = $uploaddir .$file['name'];
        } else {
            $error = true;
        }
    $data = ($error) ? array('error' => 'There was an error uploading your files in: ' . $filename) : array('files' => $files);



echo json_encode($data);
} else {
echo json_encode(array('error' => 'No data set'));
}
```

Comment: You have `url: '../api/frs-upload.php',` then you have `url: '/api/frs-upload.php?files',` with a `POST` method. Using `?` should be considered a `GET` no?

Comment: You should check `$_FILES['0']['name']` instead of `$_FILES['file']['name']` since you set numeric keys in `FormData.append`

Comment: Thank you so much @Musa, you were exactly correct.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that not all browsers support file uploads via AJAX. Your script may work fine, but your browser may be the problem. I recommend to use an iframe to do this. You can use the target attribute in a  tag to submit a form into an iframe.

Take a look at http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html for further details.

Answer (score 0):

As per what Musa said, I used $_FILE['0'] instead of $_FILE['name'] and this fixed my issue. When I looked in the console and printed out my data, the key was 0, so I should have seen this.. The answer is to check what your key is.